# Share files on iCloud drive between to different appleIDs

Tags: swift, icloud-drive, uidocumentpickervc

On OS X it seems to can share a file these days much like say dropbox or another, by right clicking it and choosing the application you want to get the link.

[image]

So in this picture for example I can Mail user A and user B a copy of the files I want to share. But how to capture/export that link so that I can write an app that is able to access a shared icloud drive file/directory. I know the functionality exists in dropbox and I think Google drive and I see a few posts here suggesting it wasn't possible [in the past] with iCloud; and yet it evidently it is these days if I can figure out how to access that link I send across in Mail within an app?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `Swift`?

Comment: Cause I want to do it within an app written in Swift :) running under iOS.